# Decimal separator in \psaxes of pstricks-add

Tags: pstricks, punctuation, pst-plot

When I use the comma option of the command \psaxes, only the y-coordinates are displayed with a comma while the x-coordinates are still displayed with a dot.

My figure is included in a somewhat big file. When I extract it and put it alone in a blank tex file, the problem disappears.

Do you have any idea where the problem could come from?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
    \psset{yunit=12cm,xunit=7.8cm}
    \begin{pspicture}(0,-0.042)(1.1,0.45)
        \readdata{\TauxRATHRRelatif}{Donnees/Chapitre1/Taux_RAT_HR_Relatif_1990_2007.txt}
        \psaxes[comma,Dx=0.1,Dy=0.05,tickstyle=bottom]{->}(0,0)(1.1,0.45)[Âge relatif,0][Taux d'évènements en \%,0]
        \psframe(0.7,0.35)(1.0,0.42)
        \psline[linecolor=blue](0.72,0.40)(0.8,0.40)
        \psline[linecolor=red](0.72,0.37)(0.8,0.37)
        \rput[l](0.82,0.4){\footnotesize Taux brut}
        \rput[l](0.82,0.37){\footnotesize Taux lissé}
        \listplot[linecolor=blue,plotNo=1,plotNoMax=2]{\TauxRATHRRelatif}
        \listplot[linecolor=red,plotNo=2,plotNoMax=2]{\TauxRATHRRelatif}
    \end{pspicture}
\caption{Taux de RAT en âge relatif (générations 1990-2007)}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

The first lines of the Taux_RAT_HR_Relatif_1990_2007.txt file are:

```
0.01    0.08950938  0.051705574
0.02    0.072002824 0.069167033
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards,

Olivier

[EDIT]: My mistake: I forgot to delete these lines at the beginning of every figure of my document:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pst@@@hlabel#1{#1}
\makeatother
```

I'm truly sorry for the waste of your time and for the double answer.

But I'm still interested in knowing how to make the comma option work after having customized the x-coordinates labels like this:

```
\newarray\ListeMois
\readarray{ListeMois}{Janvier&Février&Mars&Avril&Mai&Juin&Juillet&Août&Septembre&Octobre&Novembre&Décembre}
\makeatletter
\def\pst@@@hlabel#1{\rput[rb]{30}{\scriptsize\ListeMois(#1)}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). We can't find the problem without having something to work with. `:)`

Comment: I just wanted to know if someone already encountered the same problem because I think there is nothing specific to my code.
I nevertheless edited my first message and provided my code.

Comment: see my answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=10}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-0.042)(1.1,0.45)
   \psaxes[comma,Dx=0.1,Dy=0.1,tickstyle=bottom,  
     xLabels={Janvier,Février,Mars,Avril,Mai,Juin,Juillet,Août,Septembre,Octobre,Novembre,Décembre},
     xLabelsRot=45,xmathLabel=false,xlabelFontSize=\footnotesize]{->}(0,0)(1.1,0.45)[Âge relatif,0][Taux d'évènements en \%,0]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Herbert.
Do you know how to change the font size of the x-coordinates labels only? I looked into the documentation of pst-plot and added these line
\def\pshlabel#1{\scriptsize{#1}}
before my figure but it didn't work.
I'd like to avoid the heavy solution of writting
xLabels={\scriptsize Janvier,\scriptsize Février,etc.}.

Comment: Do _not_ use the redefinition of `\psthlabel`. Use `xlabelFontSize=...` instead. This is possible with the `pst-plot.tex` from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-plot/  or from tomorrows update of TeXLive.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped, then the question is not in the unanswered section.

Comment: Sorry for the delay: the email was sent into the spam section of my mail box.
Thanks again Herbert!